# unable to charge the powerbank in this setup

Tags: power-supply, powerbanks

The main objective is to make a perpetual powersupply (uninterrupted power supply) for a raspberry device. However, in the schematic below I have replaced the pi with a simple LED resistor since I was just prototyping the basic circuit.

[image]

Below is how it looks on the breadboard.

[image]

The micro usb terminal on the bottom is connected to the mobile charger. The terminal on the top is connected to the powerbank output. Further, the screw terminals are meant to charge the powerbank; it is connected likewise.

When there is no load on the screw terminal, it reads a voltage 4.5V. Not sure why the drop! And when under load, it drops even further, 3.6 V. This is not allowing me to charge my powerbank.

Of course, I can charge the powerbank separately, but theoretically this circuit should work, according to me. I just can't troubleshoot why this setup won't charge the powerbank.

Comment: What happens in the short moment when the relay switches?

Comment: My bad. Missed out to mention that. When I connect the mobile charger I expect the powerbank to charge. It wasn't. That was the observation. Forgot to mention that I was powering the circuit via mobile charger...

Comment: What is connected to the screw terminals?

Comment: It goes to the input of powerbank ( for charging )

Comment: According to your circuit the mobile charger 5V output is connected directly to the powerbank input, so they should both be the same voltage. If the charger reads 3.6V it's not working. If it measures 5V then you have a wiring error or bad connection (never trust a breadboard!).